# Error to render method animated component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use Animated, but I get an error:
"Element type in invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) os a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to expor your component form the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up to default and named imports.

Check the render method od 'AnimatedComponent'"

This is how I imported Animated:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Animated,  TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
```

This is how I'm using animated component

```
const AnimatedContainer = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Container);
```

The complete code:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Animated,  TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
// import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const screenHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;

class Menu extends React.Component {
    state = {
        top: new Animated.Value(screenHeight)
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        Animated.spring(this.state.top, {
            toValue: 0
        }).start();
    };

    toggleMenu = () => {
        Animated.sprint(this.state.top, {
            toValue: screenHeight
        }).start();
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <AnimatedContainer style={{ top: this.state.top }}>
                <Cover />
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleMenu}>
                    <CloseView>
                        teste
                        {/* <Ionicons name="ios-close" size={44} color="546bfb" /> */}
                 </CloseView>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Content />
            </AnimatedContainer>
        );
    }
};

export default Menu;

const AnimatedContainer = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Container);

const Container = styled.View`
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
`

const Cover = styled.View`
    height: 142px;
    background: black;
`

const Content = styled.View`
    height: ${screenHeight};
    background: #f0f3f5;
`

const CloseView = styled.View`
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    border-radius: 22px;
    background: white;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;   
`
```

Comment: Where is `Container` coming from? Is it in the same file that you're creating `AnimatedContainer` or it's being imported from somewhere else?

Comment: sorry, I edited the question. I'm using Container on styled components.

Comment: What if you move the `Container` code before `AnimatedContainer` - does that make a difference?